# set thread count for quartz thread pool

Tags: spring, quartz-scheduler

I have created file `quartz.properties` and put it in classpath.
The properties are

```
org.quartz.threadPool.class = org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool
org.quartz.threadPool.threadCount = 1
```

But when I start the application I get this message

```
Scheduler class: 'org.quartz.core.QuartzScheduler' - running locally.
NOT STARTED.
Currently in standby mode.
Number of jobs executed: 0
Using thread pool 'org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool' - with 10 threads.
Using job-store 'org.quartz.simpl.RAMJobStore' - which does not support persistence. and is not clustered.
```

Does it load property or no? I run only one thread for scheduler anyway...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I am using `spring` I did like this.
I created in my common `properties` file a property

```
quartz.threadPool.threadCount=1
```

And then set the field `quartzProperties` of `ScheduleFactoryBean` in my xml

```
<property name="quartzProperties">
    <util:properties>
        <prop key="org.quartz.threadPool.threadCount">
            ${quartz.threadPool.threadCount}
        </prop>
    </util:properties>
</property>
```

Answer (score 3):

@NikNik

`org.quartz.threadPool.threadCount` datatype must be String so It Should be

**p.put("org.quartz.threadPool.threadCount", "2");**

...

```
StdSchedulerFactory factory = new StdSchedulerFactory(p);
```

Answer (score 2):

With Spring Boot 2.1.4 I was able to set the thread pool size with the following property:

`spring.quartz.properties.org.quartz.threadPool.threadCount=2`

Comment: did not work for me

Answer (score 1):

If You are using Annotated Spring Configuration:

```
@Bean
public SchedulerFactoryBean schedulerFactoryBean() {        
    SchedulerFactoryBean scheduler = new SchedulerFactoryBean();
    Properties quartzProperties = new Properties();     
    quartzProperties.put("org.quartz.threadPool.threadCount", "1");
    scheduler.setQuartzProperties(quartzProperties);
    ...
    return scheduler;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It probabily didn't load your properties file. However, to aviod use of properties, you can configure your scheduler using java configuration:

```
Properties p = new Properties();
p.put("org.quartz.scheduler.instanceName", "Scheduler_test");
p.put("org.quartz.threadPool.threadCount", 2);
...
StdSchedulerFactory factory = new StdSchedulerFactory(p);
```

Comment: Yup. Indeed. Though I used the `properties` file